# Extract Text with its Font Details (Style,Size,color,Italic etc) from a PDF in Python

Tags: python, pdf, fonts, font-size, text-extraction

I am looking to Extract Text with its Font Details (Style,Size,color,Italic etc) from a PDF in Python.

I need to extract text and its metadata for translation purpose.Can anyone suggest any libraries for the same.

Comment: Is it possible to do that without using a library?

Answer (score 1):

There is a python library for that. Please have a look at PDFMiner.

http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html.

pdftext.py gives you the text extracted out of pdf and it also gives you other information like font and font size etc.

You can try that.

Note: **Python 3 is not supported**

Comment: `Python 3` is supported under `PDFMiner.six`.

Comment: Currently PDFMiner does not allow to extract information about font color